# systemLayoutSizeFitting returns whatever I pass in

Tags: ios, swift

So, does this function just do nothing? Is it bugged?

```
// 10000
let height = systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize).height

// 0
let height = systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
```